# API Connection Limit for R

Tags: r

I am using R to make a simple prediction model, and I am using "Jug" package to run a hosted service which provides me with predictive output.

Code is below:

```
library(randomForest)
library(jug)

#***************************************************************************************************#
#*                   BUILDING THE RANDOM FOREST MODEL                                        *#
#***************************************************************************************************#

mpg_fit<-randomForest(mpg~disp+wt+hp, mtcars)

saveRDS(mpg_fit, "mpg_fit.Rdata")

pg_fit<-readRDS("mpg_fit.Rdata")

#***************************************************************************************************#
#*         CREATING A FUNCTION THAT WILL PREDICT BASED ON THE PARAMETERS                           *#
#***************************************************************************************************#

predict_mpg<-function(disp, wt, hp){
  new_data<-data.frame(disp=as.numeric(disp), 
                       wt=as.numeric(wt),
                       hp=as.numeric(hp))
  predict(mpg_fit, newdata = new_data)
}

#***************************************************************************************************#
#*         HOSTING THE PREDICTION FUNCTION AS A WEB SERVICE                       *#
#***************************************************************************************************#

jug() %>%
  post("/mpg_api", decorate(predict_mpg)) %>%
  simple_error_handler() %>%
  serve_it()
```

The service/API runs great and returns the value when the following is used:

```
 curl -s --data "disp=160&wt=2620&hp=110" http://127.0.0.1:8080/mpg_api
```

This returns:

```
18.9758366666667
```

What I wanted to know is:

1. How scalable is this package, that is how many concurrent request can this handle if I am running this on my server.
2. Can this be used in production assuming I took care of the security aspect of it.
3. I know that Azure machine learning and predictionIO does the same, but with Jug I can control everything

I tired to read about this in the documentation of Jug but did not find my answer. If you have a better method to do the same I am eager to know.

Comment: That is a lot of (unnecessary) comments for very little code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yeah I agree, But i have a habit of doing this, helps in the complex cases